# find an valid infinite domain for quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

would this statement:
$(∀x\in D )(∃y\in D)[x < y < 1]$

be true when D is any real number between(-infinity, 1)?
and be false when 1 is included?

Comment: Yes.  If $1$ is in $D$, then for $x=1$, there is no way to make the sentence true.

Answer (score 0):

through mathematical laws, x < y < 1 (or x < y and y < 1) implies that x must be less than 1. so for the statement to be true, domain D must not contain any element such that x > 1 or x = 1.

in fact, if x < 1, then we can have y = x/2 + 1/2. if you do the math, you will find that this variable y will be greater than x but less than 1.

why that particular variable y? well, you can view this problem with a basic number line. if we pick a variable y such that it's always halfway between x and 1, then y will always be greater than x, but less than 1. we then can translate that geometric discovery into algebraic expressions.

shown work:

x < 1

y = (x - 1)/2 + 1

proving y < 1

x < 1

x-1 < 0

(x-1)/2 < 0

(x-1)/2 + 1 < 1

proving x < y

x < 1

x/2 < 1/2

x < x/2 + 1/2